# Sorting two dimensional String array as per LastName without any Collection API

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

As I attended interview yesterday for an Organisation as I done every thing is best but I was unable to build logic for a Question called :

```
String [][]Names={{"John","Pepper"},
                  {"Smith","Adams"},
                  {"Katpiller","RhodSon"},
                  {"BillMark","pearson"}
                 };
```

As per the Last Name in the above array need to be sorted without any Collection.sort or CompareTo() or any other Collection API.

My Implementation is :

```
String str[]=new String[3];


        for(int j=0; j<Name.length;j++)
         {
             for (int i=0 ; i<2; i++)
             {
                 str[i]=Name[j][i];
             }
         for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
         {
             for(int k=i+1;k<str.length;k++)
             {
                 if(str[i].compareTo(str[k])>0)
                 {
                     String temp= str[i];
                     str[i]=str[k];
                     str[k]=temp;
                 }

                 }
             System.out.print(str[i]+ " ");
          }
         System.out.println();
         }
```

Please Help me out this Hurdle Thanks in Advance

Comment: You would pretty much need to implement a sorting algorithm, there are a TON of sorting algorithms that are better than others depending on the input type, size or if its sorted or not already. Check quick sort, merge sort, etc.

Comment: It is kind of clear that you have to implement the sorting method as Edward M.B said, yet how you wanna sort it out? from a to z or z to a?

Comment: added my code which i have tried please help me out @EdwardM.B.

Comment: i wanna Sort it from a to z @KickButtowski

Comment: Since only the Collections API is forbidden, you could use `Arrays.sort`. Since you're not allowed to write a `compareTo` method you can use a lambda expression in place of the `Comparator<String[]>`. In the lambda expression you can use `Objects.compare` with `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` as comparator. That way neither a single class from the `Collections` API nor `compareTo` will appear in your code and you don't have to implement any difficult logic yourself. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @fabian i think the point is not using any libraries at all. Interviewers normally want to know if you know how to implement things from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int j = Names.length - 2; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        String name = Names[j][0];
        String lastName = Names[j][1];
        int i = j + 1;
        while(i < Names.length && strCompare(Names[i][1],lastName) < 0)
        {
            Names[i - 1][0] = Names[i][0];
            Names[i - 1][1] = Names[i][1];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        Names[i - 1][0] = name;
        Names[i - 1][1] = lastName;
    }
    for(String[] name : Names)
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(name));
```

This is an implementation of [Insertion Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort). Which sorts in place without the need of other using additional space and it works good on small inputs.

And my own reallyyyyyy bad implementation of a string comparation (String#compareTo) haha.. just to give you an idea on how to do it. (dont know if it works on all cases)

```
int strCompare(String str1, String str2){
    //gets char arrays for both strings.
    char[] strChar1 = str1.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    char[] strChar2 = str2.toUpperCase().toCharArray();

    //gets max length of the strings
    int maxLength = strChar1.length > strChar2.length? strChar1.length : strChar2.length;
    //loops character by character to compare them.
    for(int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        //if the length of the char array 1 is less than the index, then its smaller than str2.
        if(strChar1.length <= i)
            return -1;
        //if the length of the char array 2 is less than the index, then its smaller than str1.
        if(strChar2.length <= i)
            return 1;
        //compare characters and return -1 or 1 depending which one is larger.
        if(strChar1[i] < strChar2[i]){
            return -1;
        } else if (strChar1[i] > strChar2[i]){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    //return 0 to say that they are equal if the loop doesnt return anything.
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Output : [Smith, Adams][John, Pepper][Katpiller, RhodSon][BillMark, pearson]

Comment: well, like i said, its a really bad string compare implementation lol, i did it on the fly so its still needs some twicking. :P

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there are few questions to ask before trying to solve this problem :

- should the sort be case sensitive (I suppose not)
- should the sort be optimized for a great number of names (I suppose not)
- should the array be sorted in place (I suppose yes)

If the answer to the second question is true, a correct algorithm must be implemented (quick sort, merge sort), and the lowercased name must be pre-calculated, if not a direct bubble sort is enough (O(n<sup>2</sup>/2) but simpler to implement)

```
int k;
String[] temp;
for (int i=0; i<len(Names) - 1; i++) {
    k = i;
    for (j=i + 1; i<len(Names); j++) {
        if (Names[k][1].toLowerCase().compareTo(Names[i][1].toLowerCase()) < 0) {
            k = j;
        }
    }
    if (k != i) {
        temp = Names[i];
        Names[i] = Names[k];
        Names[k] = temp;
    }
}
```

If `String.compareTo` is not allowed, it simply has to be re-implemented and I suppose there are no accented chars in last name (é, è, ö, ü, etc.)

```
int compare(String a, String b) {
    int n = (a.size() < b.size()) ? a.size(), b.size();
    int delta;
    for (int i =0; i<n, i++) {
        delta = a.codePointAt(i) < b.codePointAt(j);
        if (delta != 0) {
            return delta;
        }
    }
    return len(b) - len(a);
}
```

and the line `if (Names[k][1]..compareTo(Names[i][1]...) {` has to be rewritten as :

```
if (compare(Names[k][1].toLowerCase(), Names[i][1].toLowerCase()) < 0) {
```

This algorithm is really badly optimized, but it was simple to write (and would be simple to test). It is then possible to add as needed :

- better sort algo (quick sort)
- pre calculation of lowercase last name
- management of accented characters.

Comment: The restriction here is not using the compareTo method, but everything else is like you say.